# Kubuntu 11.10: Random IO errors on HDD in RAID1 array. RMA time?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, kubuntu

I'm pretty sure I have a failing HDD here, but just want to make sure it's not some software error before I do the whole RMA song and dance routine with Western Digital.

Bascially, I have a <6 month old drive in a RAID1 array with another even newer drive. This drive is giving me seemingly random IO errors and causing a degraded RAID array. So far I have just been re-adding the drive the array and letting it rebuild itself only to have the same problem a few days later.

SMART data shows no anomalies so I'm not entirely sure where the error lies. I'm running Kubuntu 11.10 with a custom compiled 3.3.7 kernel. Below is the dmesg log for the most recent error cut off at an arbitrary point. Am I missing something obvious or is it best to RMA this guy before things get worse? Thanks as always.

```
[43161.734107] ata3: ATA_REG 0x41 ERR_REG 0x84
[43161.734110] ata3: tag : dhfis dmafis sdbfis sactive
[43161.734113] ata3: tag 0x0: 1 1 0 1  
[43161.734123] ata3.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x1 SErr 0x180000 action 0x6 frozen
[43161.734127] ata3.00: Ata error. fis:0x21
[43161.734130] ata3: SError: { 10B8B Dispar }
[43161.734134] ata3.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[43161.734142] ata3.00: cmd 60/08:00:a8:03:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
[43161.734144]          res 41/84:04:a8:03:00/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[43161.734148] ata3.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[43161.734150] ata3.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
[43161.734155] ata3: hard resetting link
[43161.734158] ata3: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[43162.220095] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[43162.260202] ata3.00: model number mismatch 'WDC WD2002FAEX-007BA0' != 'C WD2002FAEX-007BA0                   �'
[43162.260206] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-19)
[43162.260211] ata3.00: limiting speed to UDMA/133:PIO2
[43167.220123] ata3: hard resetting link
[43167.220127] ata3: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[43167.710060] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[43167.750228] ata3.00: model number mismatch 'WDC WD2002FAEX-007BA0' != 'C WD2002FAEX-007BA0                   �'
[43167.750232] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-19)
[43167.750236] ata3.00: disabled
[43172.710100] ata3: hard resetting link
[43173.620110] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[43173.640455] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
[43178.620116] ata3: hard resetting link
[43179.530113] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[43179.550748] ata3.00: ATA-8: WDC WD2002FAEX-007BA0, 05.01D05, max UDMA/133
[43179.550753] ata3.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[43179.570208] ata3.00: model number mismatch 'WDC WD2002FAEX-007BA0' != 'C WD2002FAEX-007BA0                   �'
[43179.570213] ata3.00: revalidation failed (errno=-19)
[43179.570220] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[43179.570224] ata3.00: limiting speed to UDMA/133:PIO3
[43184.530066] ata3: hard resetting link
[43184.530070] ata3: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[43185.020091] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[43185.060949] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[43185.060969] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[43185.060974] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
[43185.060980] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[43185.060983]         72 0b 47 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[43185.060995]         00 00 03 a8 
[43185.061000] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd]  Add. Sense: Scsi parity error
[43185.061006] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 03 a8 00 00 08 00
[43185.061017] end_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 936
[43185.061023] Buffer I/O error on device sdd, logical block 117
[43185.061044] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061048] sd 2:0:0:0: killing request
[43185.061062] ata3: EH complete
[43185.061075] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061123] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061134] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061140] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061145] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] READ CAPACITY(16) failed
[43185.061147] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[43185.061152] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense not available.
[43185.061155] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061166] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061175] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061185] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061193] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061198] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] READ CAPACITY failed
[43185.061202] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061209] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[43185.061215] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] Sense not available.
[43185.061226] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061235] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061245] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061254] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061263] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061274] sd 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[43185.061280] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] Asking for cache data failed
[43185.061283] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[43185.061289] sdd: detected capacity change from 2000398934016 to 0
[43185.061610] ata3.00: detaching (SCSI 2:0:0:0)
[43185.062444] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdd] Stopping disk
[43249.120042] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[43249.120046] ata4.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[43249.120051] ata4.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
[43249.120052]          res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[43249.120054] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[43249.120059] ata4: hard resetting link
[43249.120060] ata4: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
[43249.610042] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[43249.650323] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[43249.650326] ata4.00: retrying FLUSH 0xea Emask 0x4
[43249.650452] ata4.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[43249.650458] ata4: EH complete
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to check for damage on your HDD, but first, you should remove the drive from the array.

I'm going to assume that `/dev/sdd` is the problematic device, but if it's not, replace mentions of `/dev/sdd` below with the suspect device.

Then, using `badblocks` you should do a read-write test (or a non-destructive read-only test if you're pressed on time).

To do a write-mode test (which will clear the device, but that's okay because you could always rebuild the array):

```
sudo badblocks /dev/sdd -w -s
```

To do a read-only test (which might work for you because your I/O errors seem to be indicating issues with reading):

```
sudo badblocks /dev/sdd -s
```

If `badblocks` gives you *any errors*, that's not a good sign.

---

**Relevant parameter reference:**

- `-w` does a read-write test and wipes the device or partition you specify.
- `-s` shows a progress bar.
- Use `-n` instead of `-w` if for some reason you still want to do a read-write test, but you don't want any data to be erased.

Comment: Wow, I wished I had known about the badblocks utility before. Unfortunately, it seems that my drive has completely bit the dust (constant IO errors now) so I can't test it out. Thank you very much though!